# When is Monk's passive skill Pacifism effective?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

The [Pacifism](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/passive/pacifism) tooltip says if you are under a Fear, Stun or Charm effect, all damage taken is reduced by 75%.

I'm not sure what effects are counted as Fear, Stun or Charm. Some people seem to think it covers all crowd control effects, but I'm doubtful. For instance, does Frozen or Imprisonment count? When Diablo puts you in the cage and then grasps you in his hand, does it count? I'd like a complete list of what counts as a Fear, Stun or Charm effect.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can tell which effect you're under by looking at the animation over your head - Fear will show a skull, Stunned shows some floating stars and Charmed a heart, so neither frozen nor imprisonment count as one of the three.

Answer (score 1):

Fear - You appear to have a laughing skull over your head, anytime this happens this ability will pop.

Stun - You will appear to be slouched over with yellow stars over your head (like when in the cage during the Diablo fight).

Charm - (not sure what the overhead designator is on this one) but you will begin to attack your allies.  I'm not really even sure if there's mobs that Charm you to be honest.  Maybe the Spider Queen.